# Проблемы с RelativeLayout

Tags: android

У меня фон размещен относительно родительского RelativeLayout, а вот компоненты уже должны быть размещены относительно фона. Как мне это сделать в RelativeLayout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/bgd"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/google"
        android:id="@+id/btnGoogle" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gmusic"
        android:id="@+id/btnGMusic"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gmail"
        android:id="@+id/btnGMail"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnBook"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnBook"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnBook"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gbook"
        android:id="@+id/btnBook"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gplay"
        android:id="@+id/btnGPlay"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gmaps"
        android:id="@+id/btnGMaps"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnGPlay"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnGPlay"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Очевидно никак. Нет гарантированного способа точно спозиционировать элементы в контейнере при всем многообразии размеров и разрешений экрана.  Возможно только адские костыли с получением текущих параметров экрана и вычисления по ним координат элементов, но это как то не очень удачно звучит.

Comment: Только что попробовал ImageButton поместить в RelativeLayout и поставил им margin - 16dp. Сработало, но видно что совсем немного кнопки сплющены

Comment: маржины в dp не гарантируют точности позиционирования на всех типах и разрешениях экранов, будет определенная, иногда довольно существенная, погрешность, потому что учесть все комбинации довольно проблематично.